# Create a data frame new that only has the 1st 8 columns of ​the original one

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame with 1236 rows and 15 columns. I want to create a data frame new that only has the 1st 8 columns of ​the original one ,​and only has
every 3rd row of ​the original one​(only the 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc rows).

Answer (score 1):

Hear is a sample:

```
x=data.frame(x1=rnorm(1:100),x2=rnorm(1:100),x3=rnorm(1:100),x4=rnorm(1:100),x5=rnorm(1:100),x6=rnorm(1:100),x7=rnorm(1:100),x8=rnorm(1:100),x9=rnorm(1:100),x10=rnorm(1:100))
y=x[(1:33)*3,1:8]
```

I think that is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

more generally,

```
d = data.frame(matrix(nrow=1236, ncol=15))
e = d[ 3*(seq(1236/3)), 1:8]
```

Comment: Or you could do `seq(3, 1236, by=3)`